# How to delete file and directories at certain level using Windows command?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, glob

I've a folder `C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports\` and inside there are different folders and files but I want to delete only folders and files containing text say `192` in their names like

```
abc192     //This is folder
xyz192     //This is folder
pqr192xyz  //This is folder
abc192def.zip
```

I want to delete all of them(files, folder(recursively) at `C:\Users\user\Desktop\htmlreports\` with matching text `192`

Is there any way using regex I can delete both matching folders and files? `rd` command only deletes directories but does not delete files at same level. Also regex is not working with `rd`

**NOTE:** This is to be executed on Windows

Comment: `del` deletes files inside folder but not folder and hence keep empty folder there.

Comment: you're right. I need remove my comment to avoid confusion.